# Save and load data to firebase not working unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

maybe my code will mess here beacuse I'm new into firebase stuff and there is lack doc for newbie like me, so I want to make save and load data from firebase, there is 2 scene the first for `main menu` and second one the `main game`,so when firstime login or auto login, user will load `current user` data from realtime database (`I'm using firebase`)  also applies to user when back to main menu.

in the second scene itself, user load current user highscore data at first start then when game over if the `score > lasthighscore` that will save/update latest highscore to realtime database.

here the preview this is when I auto-login then playgame until game over:
[image]

it's supposed to be updated but not when back to main menu, I already try with player prefs since i erase all data when sign out so the highscore always be 0 and if login with other account that highscore is not belong to other account.
here my firebase script on main menu:

```cs
   private void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        mainPanel.SetActive(true);
        InitializeFirebase();
    }

    void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);
    }

    void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //This checks if the user (your local user) is the same as the one from the auth
        if (auth.CurrentUser != User)
        {
            //this seems the same, but user could have been null before
            bool signedIn = User != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
            if (!signedIn && User != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed out " + User.UserId);
                loginPanel.SetActive(true);
            }
            //this is important step, this user is the one you should be working with
            User = auth.CurrentUser;
            if (signedIn)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + User.UserId);
                userNameShowText.text = User.DisplayName;
                StartCoroutine(LoadUserData());
                loginPanel.SetActive(false);

                //            //highScoreMainMenu.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString("0000000");

            }
            else
            {
                loginPanel.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
    
     public IEnumerator Login(string _email, string _password)
    {
        //Call the Firebase auth signin function passing the email and password
        var LoginTask = auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_email, _password);
        //Wait until the task completes
        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => LoginTask.IsCompleted);

        if (LoginTask.Exception != null)
        {
            //If there are errors handle them
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {LoginTask.Exception}");
            FirebaseException firebaseEx = LoginTask.Exception.GetBaseException() as FirebaseException;
            AuthError errorCode = (AuthError)firebaseEx.ErrorCode;

            string message = "Login Failed!";
            switch (errorCode)
            {
                case AuthError.MissingEmail:
                    message = "Missing Email";
                    break;
                case AuthError.MissingPassword:
                    message = "Missing Password";
                    break;
                case AuthError.WrongPassword:
                    message = "Wrong Password";
                    break;
                case AuthError.InvalidEmail:
                    message = "Invalid Email";
                    break;
                case AuthError.UserNotFound:
                    message = "Account does not exist";
                    break;
            }
            warningLoginText.text = message;
        }
        else
        {
            //User is now logged in
            //Now get the result
            User = LoginTask.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", User.DisplayName, User.Email);
            warningLoginText.text = "";
            confirmLoginText.text = "Logged In";

            StartCoroutine(LoadUserData());

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

            userNameShowText.text = User.DisplayName;
            UserDataScreen(); // Change to user data UI
            confirmLoginText.text = "";
            ClearLoginFeilds();
            ClearRegisterFeilds();
        }
    }

     public IEnumerator UpdateHighScore(int _highScore)
    {
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("highscore").SetValueAsync(_highScore);

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
           //giscrore now updated
        }
    }
```

and this is for the game scene also same function for update higscore like on main menu.

```cs
void Start()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();

        YetGameOver();
        //GetScore
        score = 0;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString("00000");
        //highScoreText.text = "HI :" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0).ToString("00000");
        maxTime = .1f;
    }

   void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);
    }

    void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //This checks if the user (your local user) is the same as the one from the auth
        if (auth.CurrentUser != User)
        {
            //this seems the same, but user could have been null before
            bool signedIn = User != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
            if (!signedIn && User != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed out " + User.UserId);
            }
            //this is important step, this user is the one you should be working with
            User = auth.CurrentUser;
            if (signedIn)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + User.UserId);
                StartCoroutine(LoadUserData());
                //highScoreMainMenu.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString("0000000");

            }
        }
    }

  public void GameOver()
    {
        SaveData();
        StartCoroutine(WaitToDeath());
    }

public void SaveData()
    {
        Debug.Log("Saved");
        StartCoroutine(UpdateHighScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0)));
    }

 public IEnumerator WaitToDeath()
    {

        _CamShake.instance.shouldShake = true;

        DeathSound();

        gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);

        endHighScoreText.text = "HI :" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString("0000000");
        scoreText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        highScoreText.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);

        //_AdmobAds.instance.ShowInterstitialAd();
        isStarted = false;
        isGameOver = true;
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
//same function like main menu
public IEnumerator UpdateHighScore(int _highScore)
    {
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("highscore").SetValueAsync(_highScore);

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            //highscore are now updated
            
        }
    }

public IEnumerator LoadUserData()
    {
        //Get the currently logged in user data
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else if (DBTask.Result.Value == null)
        {
            //No data exists yet
            highScoreText.text = "0";
            endHighScoreText.text = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            //Data has been retrieved
            DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
            highScoreText.text = endHighScoreText.text = snapshot.Child("highscore").Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` but I couldn't find where you ever **set one**. Also what is `LoadUserData` and why do you wait hard `2` seconds but not until `LoadUserData` is finished? (`yield return StartCoroutine(LoadUserData());`)

Comment: @derHugo thanks for mention it, i've updated the scripts

Comment: so after `highScoreText.text = endHighScoreText.text = snapshot.Child("highscore").Value.ToString();` is seems you never store this anywhere else .. only in these texts ... do you maybe want to store it to `score = (int)snapshot.Child("highscore").Value; highScoreText.text = endHighScoreText.text = score.ToString();`

Comment: @derHugo i want to store it on endHighscoretext, then save it to database

Answer (score 0):

You don't capture child in this method. You can only capture all the data from the root. So, simply remove the child. It will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

my solution to firebase realtime database not working was that my google-services.json wasnt updated after adding the google-services.json from firebase auth. firebase, project overview cogwheel, project settings, json on that page somewhere.

and my problem with firebase auth before that was that i didnt set the Client ID in unity, window, google play games, setup, android setup.. get the id from google play console, play games services, setup & management, configuration, and figure out how to add game server credentials